# Problem with a code trying to retrieve all addresses within a specified region (Geolocator API)

Tags: python, geolocation, gis, geospatial, google-geolocation

I have written this code addressing to Geolocator API of Google Maps and it is not functional. Note that as an entry level devoloper I do this through Google collabs.

```
`import requests
import smtplib
import pandas as pd
file_path = "C:/Users/30697/Downloads/addresses.xlsx"
api_key = "MED_316KQ_4XqvYLSYa2k="
lat1 = 38.1579862
lng1 = 23.9626608
lat2 = 38.1579862
lng2 = 23.9626608
lat3 = 38.1540804
lng3 = 23.9595323
lat4 = 38.1540804
lng4 = 23.9595323

def save_addresses_to_excel(addresses, file_path):
    # Create a DataFrame with the addresses
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Address": addresses})

    # Write the DataFrame to an Excel file
    df.to_excel(file_path, index=False)
```

```
def get_addresses_in_region(api_key, lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2, lat3, lng3, lat4, lng4):
    # Define the bounds of the region
    bounds = f"{lat1},{lng1}|{lat2},{lng2}|{lat3},{lng3}|{lat4},{lng4}"

    # Make the API request
    response = requests.get(f"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?bounds={bounds}&key={api_key}")

    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Parse the response JSON
        data = response.json()

        # Extract the addresses from the response
        addresses = [result["formatted_address"] for result in data["results"]]

        return addresses
    else:
        # Return an error message
        return "Error: Could not retrieve addresses."
```

I expect a series of addresses to be displayed as a result.

Comment: you should show us your expected output and the output that you got

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding#geocoding-lookup), the `bounds` parameter is an optional **addition** to the request, which helps to refine the results. You must also specify `address`, `components`, `latlng` or `place_id`. Assuming you're trying to do reverse geocoding, you probably need to specify a single coordinate using `latlng`.